# Are there any finitely generated artinian modules that are not Noetherian?

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, modules, noncommutative-algebra

It is well known that for *rings*, Artinian implies Noetherian (the famous Hopkins–Levitzki theorem) and it is also well known that there are Artinian *modules* which are not Noetherian. A simple example can be found in

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artinian_module#Relation_to_the_Noetherian_condition

Since rings are always finitely generated modules over themselves (all rings considered are unital), it seemed natural to me to ask whether there are *finitely generated* modules, which are Artinian but not Noetherian (the example given in the reference is clearly not finitely generated). I guess that if the statement "every finitely generated artinian module is noetherian" was true, I would have seen it in any standard text book on algebra, and since I haven't, I guess it's not. But still, I can't find a counter-example for this. Perhaps I'm missing something completely trivial here. I will be happy to see an example of such module or a proof that there are no (just a reference will be much appreciated too of course).

Comment: Wouldn't this statement reduce to cyclic modules (one generator)? Then, at least if the ring is commutative (I can't figure out whether you are making this assumption), a cyclic module is a free module over a quotient ring, and so noetherian and artinian properties appear to be equivalent.

Comment: I changed the tag "commutative-algebra", which I put by mistake, to "noncommutative-algebra". The answer about the commutative case was great. so was the comment, that after reading Simon's answer, I understood that it says pretty much the same thing. thanks. I'm still interested in the noncommutative case. 

Comment: I just followed the wikipedia link that you gave and it gives links to two articles that show that cyclic Artinian modules need not be Noetherian http://plms.oxfordjournals.org/content/s3-35/1/55 and http://jlms.oxfordjournals.org/content/55/2/231 I don't have access to either so can't say much more 

Comment: thanks a lot Simon! It settles it completely. I feel stupid for missing the link from the article on wikipedia I linked myself. I promise to do my homework batter for the next question...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Suppose you have an Artinian but not Noetherian finitely generated $R$ module $M$. Let $0\leq M_1\leq M_2\leq \cdots \leq M_n=M$ be a finite chain of $R$-modules such that each composition factor $M_i/M_{i-1}$ is cyclic for each $i$.

Certainly each composition is Artinian since subquotients of Artinian modules are Artinian. Also one of the composition factors must be non-Noetherian since extensions of Noetherian modules by Noetherian modules are Noetherian. Thus, we may assume that $M$ is a *cyclic* $R$-module.

Now if $R$ is commutative, $M$ is a quotient ring $R/I$ which is Artinian as such and so Noetherian also, as you say.

If $R$ is non-commutative then I'm not sure what the answer is.

---

Added: It seems from the wikipedia article linked from the question that Hartley showed that there are cyclic Artinian and non-Noetherian modules over certain non-commutative rings and Cohn gave another construction nearly twenty years later. See the links I give in the comments on the question for precise references.